# sed remove double quote pair spanning lines

Tags: sed

In my OpenDKIM key file, I have extra quotes that can't go in "proper" DNS records. (I'm surprised the OpenDKIM devs allow this in their file, but that's another story.)

In RegEx, it is two double quotes with whitespace that includes a new line. This is the pattern that needs to be removed.

Here is what I **have**:

```
dkim._domainkey IN  TXT ( "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; t=s; s=email; "
      "p=MyRidicul0u2e70nGK37pqawrje9vfo34qjfijsfj[o4ijq39408jfaes04fj34q09qj340rf93qw4jfp9q834jfw8934fj3qw4fj" )  ;
```

I **need** to remove those quotes and new line to get this:

```
dkim._domainkey IN  TXT ( "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; t=s; s=email; p=MyRidicul0u2e70nGK37pqawrje9vfo34qjfijsfj[o4ijq39408jfaes04fj34q09qj340rf93qw4jfp9q834jfw8934fj3qw4fj" )  ;
```

And, I want to use `sed` to do this, but `awk` answers are still welcome.

My best effort is something like this:

```bash
sed 's/"\s"//' opendkim.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> extra quotes that can't go in "proper" DNS records. (I'm surprised the OpenDKIM devs allow this in their file, but that's another story.)

That's a perfectly valid DNS record according to RFC 1035. [TXT records](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1035#section-3.3.14) consist of one **or more** "character strings" (each of which is written either as a quoted string or unquoted bareword within zone files), while the parentheses allow a record to be specified across multiple lines when stored in a text-format zone file (see [page 35](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1035#page-35)).

The [DKIM specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6376#section-3.6.2.2) says that all strings found within a "_domainkey" TXT record are con­cate­nat­ed together to produce the value, as the length of a single string in DNS is limited to 255 bytes and it would be impossible to fit a decent-size RSA key into that limit. It is therefore not only normal but practically required for a DKIM public key to span multiple strings.

If your DNS server system does not accept this, then it has a weird definition of "proper."

```
$ cat x.zone
$TTL 1h
@ IN SOA . . 1 1h 1h 1h 1h
@ IN NS .
dkim._domainkey IN  TXT ( "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; t=s; s=email; "
      "p=MyRidicul0u2e70nGK37pqawrje9vfo34qjfijsfj[o4ijq39408jfaes04fj34q09qj340rf93qw4jfp9q834jfw8934fj3qw4fj" )  ;

$ named-checkzone example.com x.zone 
zone example.com/IN: loaded serial 1
OK

$ knot-kzonecheck --verbose x.zone
No semantic error found

$ nsd-checkzone example.com x.zone 
zone example.com is ok

$ ldns-read-zone x.zone
dkim._domainkey.    3600    IN  TXT "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; t=s; s=email; " "p=MyRidicul0u2e70nGK37pqawrje9vfo34qjfijsfj[o4ijq39408jfaes04fj34q09qj340rf93qw4jfp9q834jfw8934fj3qw4fj"
```

Your `sed` example doesn't work because sed is a line-oriented tool; it processes the `s///` command separately every line, not once for the entire file. To make it work otherwise, GNU sed has the `-z` option to use NUL as the "line separator" (which technically remains line-based, but `\n` is no longer special). There is additionally more than one whitespace character that your regex doesn't account for.

```
sed -z -E 's/"\s+"//'
```

Another way to achieve the same is to use a different tool to remove the line breaks first:

```
tr -d '\n' | sed -E 's/"[[:space:]]+"//g'
```

DNS zonefile parsers can be used to reformat the records into a single line:

```
ldns-read-zone opendkim.txt | sed ...
```

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
import dns.zonefile
with open("opendkim.txt", "r") as fh:
    rrsets = dns.zonefile.read_rrsets(fh.read(),
                                      rdclass=None,
                                      default_ttl=0)
for rrset in rrsets:
    print(rrset.name)
    for rr in rrset:
        string = b"".join(rr.strings)
        print(string.decode())
```

Comment: The information about a proper zone file is good to know. However, I need something that can be copy-pasted into a zone field for a site like Digital Ocean or GoDaddy, which do not accept concatenated strings. The explanation is good, but the proper `sed` expression helps solve my particular problem and it worked like a charm.